# ggvis in R: Change color when mouse hover

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

Is there a code that can realize the first example picture on the GGVIS homepage?

https://ggvis.rstudio.com/

[image]

The function I want is that the color changes when I hover over the bar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `fill.hover` argument:

```
library(ggvis)

faithful %>% 
ggvis(~eruptions, fill := "#fff8dc", fill.hover := "#fcb5a2") %>%
  layer_histograms(width = 0.25)
```